# Given s family of quadratics, plot them and show the minima of each curve

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, homework

family function x^2 - 2*(m - 2)*x + m - 2

> a) Create a `Manipulate` to explore the behaviour of the functions of this family for m ∈ [-10,10]. Mark the minimum value of the parabolas with a red point. What do you observe about these points? Use the interval [-20,20] for x.
>
> b) Collect/create the coordinates of the minimum value for the 21 values of m (integer values from -5 to 5). Find the coefficients a,b and c such that the points are on the curve of equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

I couldn't solve the question b

Here what I wrote:

```
f1[m_, x_] = x^2 - 2*(m - 2)*x + m - 2; 
Assuming[-10 <= m <= 10, 
  Minimize[{f1[m, x], -20 <= x <= 20, -10 <= m <= 10}, x] // Simplify]
```

It gives:

> ```
> {-6 + 5 m - m^2, {x -> -2 + m}}
> ```

Please help.

Comment: What is the family of functions that are of concern? Are they given by `f[m_][ x_] :=  x^2 - 2*(m - 2)*x + m - 2;`

Comment: yes the function is x^2 - 2*(m - 2)*x + m - 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part b of the question has two errors. For integer values of m from -5 to 5 you get 11 values, not 21. Second, the formula in the b question must be `a x^2 + b x + c == y` . **Tell your teacher, that he asked nonsense**. With this corrections you get

```
f1[m_, x_] = x^2 - 2*(m - 2)*x + m - 2;
    Assuming[-10 <= m <= 10, 
    min = Minimize[{f1[m, x], -20 <= x <= 20, -10 <= m <= 10}, x] // 
    Simplify; {ymin[m_], xmin[m_]} = {min[[1]], x /. min[[2]]}]

sol = Solve[
  Table[a xmin[m]^2 + b xmin[m] + c == ymin[m], {m, -10, 10}], {a, b, 
   c}, Reals]

(*   {{a -> -1, b -> 1, c -> 0}}   *)

pl1 = Plot[a x^2 + b x + c /. First@sol, {x, -10, 10}];
pl2 = ListPlot@Table[{xmin[m], ymin[m]}, {m, -10, 10}];
Show[pl1, pl2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asked to find the interpolating polynomial through the coordinates of the minima of the family of functions for different values of `m`.

#### Using interpolation

One solution using interpolation as prescribed is

```
minimaCoordinates = {x /. Last[#], First[#]} &@
     Minimize[f1[#, x], x] & /@ Range[-10, 10];
interpol[x_] = ExpandAll@InterpolatingPolynomial[minimaCoordinates, x]
(* x - x^2 *)
```

You can see that the solution is $a=-1$, $b=1$, $c=0$.

You can also visualize the result

```
Plot[interpol[x], {x, Sequence @@ MinMax[minimaCoordinates[[All, 1]]]},
 Epilog -> Point[minimaCoordinates]]
```

[image: Visualization of the minima and the interpolating polynomial]

#### Without interpolation

Of course, this can also be obtained along the lines of your attempt. You are missing the crucial final step of identifying your result with a polynomial.

```
(# /. First@Solve[First[#] == x, m]) &@ 
  With[{x = x /. First@Solve[D[f1[m, x], x] == 0, x]},
   {x, f1[m, x]}
   ] // ExpandAll
(* {x, x - x^2} *)
```